# How to create interface for event return in a parameter?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component which has the following interface:

```
interface IPreTicketListProps {
    onEditPreTicket: (preTicketId: string) => { preTicketId: string };
    onCreateSuggestedOperation: (preTicketId: string) => { preTicketId: string };
}
```

I need that, when instantiating this component and using these methods, it returns the property "preTicketId" and as a string;

```
<PreTicketList
    onEditPreTicket={preTicketId => alert(preTicketId)}
    onCreateSuggestedOperation={preTicketId => alert(preTicketId)}
/>
```

**ERROR**:

```
ERROR in src/pages/HomePage/index.tsx:26:38
TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ preTicketId: string; }'.
    24 | 
    25 |                                <PreTicketList
  > 26 |                                        onEditPreTicket={preTicketId => alert(preTicketId)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your signature ought to be
`onEditPreTicket: (preTicketId: string) => void;`

based on how you're expecting to consume it. Your function of  `onEditPreTicket={preTicketId => alert(preTicketId)}` does return void

If you do wish for it to match that signature you'd need to return the value after executing alert

Comment: Even doing this way the signature outside looks like this:

Parameter 'preTicketId' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

should be string;

Comment: signature outside where?